# What could be done with web shell on unrooted android device?

Tags: php, android, root

Is it possible to control unrooted android device through a web shell?

I've been trying to execute various php shells but the whole response is error statements like this

[image]

- php is installed and all other php pages works fine
- The tested php shells works fine on another controlled systems

Comment: What do you mean by"control"? Are you aware of the security separations in Android?

Comment: I mean: to be able to execute and use the shell properly without any errors

Comment: So you don't want to control the unrooted Android device, you want to "control" the shell?

Comment: Yeah, But if I'm able to control the shell I must be able to control the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web server such as [Palapa Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfanla.android.pws&hl=en) is installed on the Android device and the Android device is capable to execute PHP scripts then you can definately get the shell access of the device.

Note: Android supports a beautiful and the robust concept of **sandboxing** such that each application runs as different user. Once you will get the shell access on the device you will get the privelleges of the application that is executing the webshell.